# ¿Como manejar objetos en Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, ionic3, ionic-framework

Estoy realizando una aplicación para generar facturas, el problema que tengo es que traigo un cliente y un producto de la base de datos pero no puedo asignar la data a una nueva variable para así poder hacer las respectivas operaciones del precio del producto con el descuento del respectivo cliente. Comparto parte el código donde en el constructor asigno a una nueva variable para poder utilizar el objeto pero cuando lo quiero utilizar me indica  undefined. Solo puedo utilizarlo dentro del método getCliente().

```js
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: HttpClient,public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    public productosProvider: ProductosProvider, public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public facturasProvider: FacturaProvider, public clientesProvider: ClientesProvider,
    public rutasProvider: RutasProvider, public alertController: AlertController,
    public empresaProvider: EmpresasProvider, public detalleProvider: DetalleProvider
  ) {
    //cargar datos de clientes
    
    this.clienteID = this.navParams.get('id');

   

    this.clienteActual = this.getCliente(this.clienteID);   
  }

 
  //metodo que obtiene el cliente y sus datos para utilizarlos
  getCliente(id:any) {
    this.clientesProvider.getCliente(id).then(data => {
      this.cliente = data;
  
     
      return data;
    })
  }
```

El siguiente código es el que estoy utilizando en el provider del cliente

```js
@Injectable()
export class ClientesProvider {

 
  apiUrl= 'https://api-tomza.herokuapp.com/api/';

  
  constructor(public http: HttpClient //public RutasProvider: RutasProvider
  ){

  }
          
  //metodo para obtener todos los clientes de una ruta especifica
  getClientes(ruta:String) {
     return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}clientes?filter[where][ruta]=${ruta}`);
  }

  //metodo para traer un cliente especifico por id
  getCliente(id:String) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}clientes/${id}`).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes entender que estas en un nuevo mundo de programación asíncrona, y lo que estas haciendo en el constructor es cargar datos que no sabes si van a tener éxito o no.

Por lo tanto la siguiente linea, no está controlada totalmente

```
this.clienteActual = this.getCliente(this.clienteID);
```

con lo cual debes manejar el caso cuando no obtengas valores tambien, es un error común en Ionic cuando empiezas:

```
//no es muy recomendable usar el tipo any acostumbrate a usar String, number, etc.
//por algo typescript es un lenguaje tipado
getCliente(id:any) {
    this.clientesProvider.getCliente(id).then(data => {
      this.cliente = data;//asumiendo que tienes un objeto del mismo tipo
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Lamentablemente no se como esté tu Provider para así tratar de ayudarte un poco más.

Ademas nota que el valor se está asignando a la variable cliente.

```
getCliente(id:String) {

  this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}clientes/${id}`);


}
```

tu http.get ya retorna una promesa.

Comment: Hola David muchas gracias por tu respuesta, compartí el código de mi provider para que puedas verlo, y tienes razón es mi primera experiencia con Ionic y me ha costado un poco entender su funcionamiento

Comment: por lo mismo te comento que tu valor esta siendo guardado en la variable cliente y en la variable clienteActual estas almacenando la promesa. Aúnque es más conveniente trabajar con observables.